# map `symbfit` to `symbf` for digits

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode-math, lucida

The goal is to make vectors bold italic using the command `\symbfit` from `LucidaBrightMathOT.otf`.

However, `\symbfit` does not work for digits, as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[]{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\symbfit{#1}}
\begin{document}
\(x\), \(\vec{x}\)

\(0\), \(\vec{0}\), want: \(\symbf{0}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it somehow possible to map `symbfit` to `symbf` for digits? For example, with the `range` option of fontspec?

Comment: I don't think that there is an official interface, and there is an open issue about it https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/467. You could try `\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{\int_step_inline:nn{10}
   {\__um_mathmap_noparse:nnn {bfit}{\int_eval:n{47+#1}}{\int_eval:n{"1D7CD+#1}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select by cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy{\vec}{\schmidt_vec:n}}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \schmidt_vec:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{\symbf{0}}
    {1}{\symbf{1}}
    {2}{\symbf{2}}
    {3}{\symbf{3}}
    {4}{\symbf{4}}
    {5}{\symbf{5}}
    {6}{\symbf{6}}
    {7}{\symbf{7}}
    {8}{\symbf{8}}
    {9}{\symbf{9}}
   }
   {\symbfit{#1}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\(x\), \(\vec{x}\)

\(0\), \(\vec{0}\), want: \(\symbf{0}\)

\end{document}
```

I guess you actually only want 0 to be specially treated, though.

[image]

Comment: Thx. Yes, I only need zero and one.